# checkboxes on sql result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
          A                   B                   C        

P_id | name | add     P_id  |  t_id        t_id |  paper  
-----------------     --------------     ------------------ 
  1   sam    ca         1        1           1      asdxa  
  2   john   de         2        1           2      dgfv  
  3   sam    jk         3        2           3      decgf  
  4   sam    bc         4        3           4      ergvtr
```

Now I can easily make a search. Suppose, here i enter the name 'sam' then it will display.

sam ca
sam jk
sam bc

now i want to make checkboxes on each result so that if i click on a particular checkbox it should display the related paper from table C. Plz suggest me how to do this in php. I have already done the MySQL part.

suppose if click on the checkbox of 'sam jk' then it should display 'dgfv'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT paper FROM C WHERE t_id=3";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

if(@$_POST['checkbox']['sam_jk']) echo $mysql_result($sql, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the P_id on each checkbox, using the value attribute.
Once it's clicked or submitted, you should trigger an event to do a new search.

The value attribute had been fed with P_id, so you'll join table B and C, using t_id, and select C.paper field.

Was that clear? If it wasn't, let me know.